# Track visibility not support field many2many in odoo 12

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

I am trying to record a change history with the many2many field using mail.thread but it fails

track_visibility = 'onchange' not working

Help me solve this problem?

Comment: Could you please share more Info? What have you tried exactly? Some Code would be helpful.

Comment: I have a field of many2many form to model res.user:
share_user = fields.Many2many(comodel_name="res.users", relation="model_share_user_rel", string="Share with account", track_visibility='onchange', default=lambda self: self.env.user )
I want the current user to add or delete item on this filed to record the operation history.

Comment: @CZoellner did anyone found the solution?

Comment: There is a lot of [old discussion here](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/10149). At the end there are some links to 2 PRs with modules, trying to add that functionality. Maybe that's a bit of a help for you.

Answer (score 1):

Add this after the class name.

```
_inherit = ['mail.thread', 'mail.activity.mixin']
```

Then try:

```
track_visibility="onchange"
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. However, it only works for fields like Char, Date. As for filed many2many, when I add or delete an item, the log doesn't work.

Comment: hi @nguyenthanhDinh did you found the way to track many2many field? i am looking for exactly same this